# c# threading Timer needs to stop itself async socket code

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timer

I have timed code that checks for dead peers. I use System.Threading.Timer to do that. The detection code works and I call it like this :

```
Timer SocketKPATimer = new Timer(delegate { timedcode(state); }, null, 5000, 5000);
```

where state is a StateObject that's used to

```
Socket handler = state.workSocket;
```

and later ...

```
handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
//I need to stop the Timer here
```

The method itself is defined as 
    `static void timedcode(StateObject state) {...}`

now the problem is that after I detect that something went wrong with the peer I need the SocketKPATimer to stop and I can't.
How do I need to modify timedcode so I can stop the timer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you are going to get access to the `SocketKPATimer` is to pass the `Timer` into the `timedcode(state)` method in the state object. That means you will have to create a class that contains properties for the `Socket` and a `Timer`. Then you can define the `Timer` first and then instantiate it with a delegate and reference the `Timer`. This does not handle any sort of concurrency issues with accessing the 'Timer'. You should be using typical multi-threading techniques for that.

Example:

```
class State
{
    public Socket WorkSocket { get; set; }
    public System.Threading.Timer TimerThingy { get; set; }
}

private void Nothing()
{
    Socket someSocket = null;
    System.Threading.Timer socketKPATimer = null;

    State state = new State();

    state.WorkSocket = someSocket;
    state.TimerThingy = socketKPATimer;

    socketKPATimer = new System.Threading.Timer(delegate { timedcode(state); }, null, 5000, 5000);
}

private void timedcode(object state)
{
    var s = state as State;
    Socket hander = s.WorkSocket;
    System.Threading.Timer timer = s.TimerThingy;
    hander.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
}
```

Comment: yes, that does it in my testcode. I did have to move `state.TimerThingy = SocketKPATimer;` after the SocketKPATimer's creation otherwise the code throws a nullreference exception upon Disposing the Timer. Thank you very much.